# How to create Sidechain?

Tags: blockchain, sidechain

I have two questions regarding sidechain.

Q1. Do we need specific technology stack to create sidechain ?
Q2. Can any public blokchain can be use for sidechain ? also how can i use sidechain with Ethereum.

looking forward
Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [loom](https://loomx.io/). They are actively implementing sidechains. If you want to be more techincal, take a look at [Plasma](https://plasma.io/)

Comment: your second question has grammatical mistakes and I wasn't able to figure what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

Plasma MVP is a good start, to create side chains of Ethereum. There is already a prototype by OmiseGo.

https://github.com/omisego/plasma-mvp

Answer (score 1):

A lot of implementations are still experimental. It's not the easiest thing to do. Some people use **State Channels**, some create **Plasma Chains**, and then there are some others that use **non-blockchain based** implementations and just compute using standard languages.

**Here are some built out code examples of each:**

**State Channels**: https://github.com/SpankChain/general-state-channels

**Plasma Chain**: https://github.com/LayerXcom/plasma-mvp-vyper

- Check out **Loom** as well, mentioned above by @shane

**Private Function Contracts**: https://github.com/enigmampc/secret-contracts

So to answer your questions...

1. There is *no* standard technology stack
2. That is still to be determined, but I don't see why you could not use another blockchain platform as a sidechain.

Comment: is loom network a good one to try?

Comment: @Unreality Yes loom is great. I really like that they support multiple language implementations for writing smart contracts. They have a simple CLI as well.